# How to quote arguments in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to output a text file which has MIPS code, however it keeps picking up the arguments and won't write them to the text file.

Code:

```
function errorMessage() {
echo "You have entered the wrong amount of arguments. The default files will now be used"
echo '#input.txt' > input.txt
"add $s0 $s1 $s2" >> input.txt
"sub $s2 $t0 $t3" >> input.txt
"add $s0 $s1 $z2" >> input.txt
"lw $t1 8($t2)" >> input.txt
"addi $t3 $s0 -9" >> input.txt
"sw $s3 4($t0)" >> input.txt
"lw $t11 70000($s0)'" >> input.txt

}
```

Results:

```
 #input.txt    
    add   
    sub   
    add   
    lw  8()    
    addi   -9    
    sw  4()    
    lw  70000()
```

Comment: You should pass the arguments to the function.. What your function called in the code?

Comment: You need to escape special characters. Try `echo "add \$s0 \$s1 \$s2" >> input.txt`

Comment: use single quotes so they don't expand. You also either need echo on every line or just a single redirection `> input.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of creating files by writing to them is by using whats called a Here Document.

```
#!/bin/bash
(
cat <<'EOF'
#input.txt
add $s0 $s1 $s2
sub $s2 $t0 $t3
add $s0 $s1 $z2
lw $t1 8($t2)
addi $t3 $s0 -9
sw $s3 4($t0)
lw $t11 70000($s0)
EOF
) > input.txt
```

What this does is it takes the text between `cat <<'EOF'` and `EOF` and writes it to input.txt. Because the `EOF` in `cat <<'EOF'` is quoted, the variables that have a $ before them are not treated as bash variables but rather real text. You can replace the string `EOF` for anything that you want. You can learn more about Here Documents here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for `$s0` to be output literally, you need to use single-quotes rather than double quotes:

```
echo 'add $s0 $s1 $s2' >> input.txt
```

You can improve your script by writing once (using a here-document) rather than reopening `input.txt` for every line:

```
function errorMessage() {
echo >&2 "You have entered the wrong amount of arguments. The default files will now be used"
cat <<'END' >input.txt
#input.txt
add $s0 $s1 $s2
sub $s2 $t0 $t3
add $s0 $s1 $z2
lw $t1 8($t2)
addi $t3 $s0 -9
sw $s3 4($t0)
lw $t11 70000($s0)
END
}
```